# Problem import ResizeSensor into typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use css-element-queries/ResizeSensor in my typescript app with webpack.

I have added the npm and the npm includes a .d.ts file. 
The problem is that when I type this:

```
new ResizeSensor(element, cb);
```

the typescript compiler generates:

```
new ResizeSensor_1.default(element, cb);
```

and of course that is incorrect. ResizeSensor returns a single class and the correct code that TS should create is:

```
new ResizeSensor_1(element, cb);
```

The ResizeSensor.d.ts file contains:

```
export declare type ResizeSensorCallback = (size: { width: number; height: number; }) => void;

declare class ResizeSensor {
    constructor(element: Element | Element[], callback: ResizeSensorCallback);
    detach(callback?: ResizeSensorCallback): void;
    reset(): void;

    static detach(element: Element | Element[], callback?: ResizeSensorCallback): void;
    static reset(element: Element | Element[]): void;
}

export default ResizeSensor;
```

and I am importing it like this:

```
import ResizeSensor from 'css-element-queries/src/ResizeSensor';
```

TS complains if I put ResizeSensor in {} and I have tried all the other forms of the import statement that I know of.

My tsconfig.json file includes the following options:

```
"target": "es5"
```

and

```
"module": "amd"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `esModuleInterop` compiler option
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: unfortunately that didn't change anything. It did add a var _importDefault to the beginning of the output file but it didn't change the calling site at all, which is where the problem is.

Comment: Also, enabling this setting completely broke all my existing imports